# Как отключить .ecryptfs?

Tags: bash, linux

Занимает 90 гектаров, и толку мало. Можно ли эту папку удалить?

Answer (score 2):

Если Вы уверены, что в ней нет важных для Вас шифрованных данных, то да, можно удалить.

Comment: Ох, лучше бы вы мне говорили так.
Я что-то не правильно удалил,... в общем, полноценно ОСь не загружается, кроме того, наутилус и другие оконные приложения не запускаются...
Что самое интересное, эта директория, которую я хотел удалить - цела и не вредима. Как используя её, восстановить все данные? желательно сразу же восстанавливать в одно место - буду резервную копию делать и ставить новую убунту.

Comment: Ну, видимо настройки грохнули. А кто просил включать шифрование домашнего пользователя? Если ничего ценного нет, то проще систему переустановить с нуля. Да и заодно правильно создать разделы и назначить права. Если это не устраивает - дайте знатйь, все равно помогу

Comment: Мне нужно увидеть файлы - или из юускнзеаы или из моей пользовательской директории, куда я не могу достать.
Выбрать файлы и скопировать либо на флешку, либо в cloud какой-то.

Comment: команда

grep ecryptfs /var/log/syslog | tail -n1

выдала следующее

ecryptfs-unwrap-passphrase: Error attempting to open [/home/<user>/.ecryptfs/wrapped-passphrase] for reading

тут я вспомнил, что именно этот файл я удалил первым по ошибке... также я нашел, что даже если бы я удалил именно правильную папку - ось не смогла бы полноценно загрузиться....

Comment: Плохо. Но вообще, как известно, файлы при удалении с винчестера не удаляются физически. А просто стирается запись в каталоге. Можно попытаться воспользоваться утилитами типа undelete или средствами восстановления данных вроде r-studio